# POST method problem in php?

Tags: php

As I am using **FCKEditor** to develop small web site to manage site contents dynamically. When i add more content in the **FCKEditor** is working fine in my staging server where if i tested same in my live server, which throwing error as `"500 Internal server error"`. I was not able find out the problem, please help me out.

Sri

Comment: please provide details on the error. e.g. relevant entries to phperror.log

Comment: Was your live server already working with this site before you changed the content? Also, what content did you change? Can you get a single test php file to work (a very basic hello world page for example). Also are you running apache server? Did you do anything with any .htaccess files?

Answer (score 2):

It probably isn't a problem directly related to FCKEditor, but most likely a configuration issue.  Do you have access to your error logs?